# HTML Parsing Error

Tags: html, mozilla, user-agent, parsing-error

I can't find out what the problem is, and why I keep receiving this error in Internet Explorer 8, as it's the only error that I am receiving. Any thoughts as to what it means, or a simple solution? I haven't noticed any problems with my code though, it's just the message that bugs me.

Webpage error details.

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
>   .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729) Timestamp: Mon, 7 Sep 2009 19:11:13
>   UTC

```
Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
```

Comment: Sounds like you are modifying dom elements before they are reliably available.

Comment: What does that actually mean?

Comment: I fixed the problem thanks, the answers below worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is there in the error - [KB927917](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917) says:

> This problem occurs because a child
>   container HTML element contains script
>   that tries to modify the parent
>   container element of the child
>   container. The script tries to modify
>   the parent container element by using
>   either the innerHTML method or the
>   appendChild method.
>
> For example, this problem may occur if
>   a DIV element is a child container in
>   a BODY element, and a SCRIPT block in
>   the DIV element tries to modify the
>   BODY element that is a parent
>   container for the DIV element.

Answer (score 3):

The error message you are getting indicates "KB927917". This is a reference to an entry in Microsoft's knowledge base.

More specifically : [Why do I receive an "Operation aborted" error message when I visit a Web page in Internet Explorer?](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B927917&x=11&y=13)

On that page, there are informations for both end-users and developpers ; those might help you understand what is causing this problem.

This part seems interesting (quoting) :

> This problem occurs because a child
>   container HTML element contains script
>   that tries to modify the parent
>   container element of the child
>   container. The script tries to modify
>   the parent container element by using
>   either the innerHTML method or the
>   appendChild method.
>
> For example, this problem may occur if
>   a DIV element is a child container in
>   a BODY element, and a SCRIPT block in
>   the DIV element tries to modify the
>   BODY element that is a parent
>   container for the DIV element.

There is also a link to this blog entry : [What Happened to Operation Aborted?](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx)

On that entry, there is exactly the message you are getting *(which seems to be the way IE8 deals with that problem -- where older versions were just displaying some kind of alert box and a blank page)* ; so, might you too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This workaround works fine:

```
setTimeout( function() {
    "scary DOM manipulations"
}, 0 );
```